# How to set the unique id for element in the loop with Mootools?

Tags: javascript, mootools

i need to set the unique numeric rel attributes for anchor elements in table with class "tdresult". Im trying to set them in the loop, but im not very good at Javascript and probably don't undestood loops.

```
$$('.tdresult').each(function(chooseClass) {
    var ellen=chooseClass.getElements('a').length;
    var eli=chooseClass.getElements('a').each(function(el){
    for (i=0; i<ellen; i++){
    var elic=el.set('rel',i++);  //trying to set numeric ids for anchor els (from 0 to //max (ellen)
    }
    });
    chooseClass.addEvent('mouseenter', function(el) {
    infoGet(1,uniqueid); // function that sets the ajax request using unique id from loop
        }); 
});
```

Can anyone advise me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want if I understand the Question correctly

```
var offset = 0;
$$('.tdresult').each(function(chooseClass) {
 chooseClass.getElements('a').each(function(el){
      el.set('rel',offset); 
      el.addEvent('mouseenter', function(uniqueid) {
         return function() {
           infoGet(1,uniqueid); 
         }
      }(offset)); 
      offset++
 });
 
});
```

`offset` is incremented with the loop but is declared outside of it. Every time the loop runs, it will be the same `offset` variable being incremented. The loop that was there previously was not necessary.

One question though... why would you set the `rel` attribute to a number? see http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_rel.asp for a list of valid values. Also note that none of the major browsers make use of this attribute anyways. (Epic fail on standards support for everyone)

**EDIT**

I noticed what you were trying to do with the event listener. I've modified the code to store the current offset in a closure with the event handler. The function in the event handler is immediately run with the current `offset`. Inside the function this is referred to as `uniqueid`. The function then returns the real event handler function but maintains use of the `uniqueid` variable (not offset, but the value of offset at the time the outer function was called).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're doing, but it *looks* like you are:

1. Finding every `a` element inside each `.tdresult` element
2. adding a unique value to the `rel` attribute to each
3. adding a mouseenter event to each which uses that `rel` attribute

If you want to store a unique value, try [`store`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:store) and [`retrieve`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:retrieve):

```
var unique_id = 0;
$$('.tdresult a').each(function(el){
    el.store('unique_id',unique_id);
    el.addEvent('mouseenter', function(evt) {
        infoGet(1,this.retrieve('unique_id')); 
    });     
    unique_id++;
});
```

Though it's possible I'm misunderstanding the task.

Answer (score 1):

This is much easier in mootools cause each gives you a counter and as your in a closure at the each loop you doent need to store the id. Check out in [mooShell](http://mooshell.net/dBekj/) (activate console)

```
$$('td a').each(function(el, uId){
        el.addEvent('mouseenter', function() {
               infoGet(1, uId);
        });     
});
```

Comment: $$('.tdresult a').each(function(el, uId){
        el.addEvent('mouseenter', function() {
               infoGet(1, uId+1);
        });     
});

// this good, but i need to set mouseover in all td area not just for its child (a)

Comment: To you need a specific id or is this worse.

Comment: it's very difficult to set specific ids to elements requested by ajax, because the're over 9000 of them :( but anyways big thanks to u! i have solved my problem for 50%